# SQL Server Query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please help me to find the best solution for this puzzle?

How to I go from this table here:

```
ID_LOCAL ID_STATUS
-------- ---------
65       0 
65       0 
65       0
65       0
65       0
65       0
65       0
65       1
65       2
93       0
96       0
186      1
```

To this result here:

```
ID_LOCAL TOTAL ID_STATUS=0 ID_STATUS=1 ID_STATUS=2
-------- ----- ----------- ----------- -----------
65       9     7           1           1 
93       1     1           0           0
96       1     1           0           0
186      1     0           1           0
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried?  If you want to do code-by-request then you should hire a consultant.  Stack Overflow is for assistance with specific issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select ID_LOCAL,
       count(*) as Total,
       count(case when ID_STATUS = 0 then 1 end) as Status0,
       count(case when ID_STATUS = 1 then 1 end) as Status1,
       count(case when ID_STATUS = 2 then 1 end) as Status2
from YourTable
group by ID_LOCAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table name is `Table`

```
select 
  ID_LOCAL,
  count(*) as TOTAL,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) from Table WHERE ID_LOCAL = outr.ID_LOCAL AND ID_STATUS=0) AS [ID_STATUS=0],
  (SELECT COUNT(*) from Table WHERE ID_LOCAL = outr.ID_LOCAL AND ID_STATUS=1) AS [ID_STATUS=1],
  (SELECT COUNT(*) from Table WHERE ID_LOCAL = outr.ID_LOCAL AND ID_STATUS=2) AS [ID_STATUS=2]
FROM Table outr
GROUP BY ID_LOCAL
```

**OR**

```
select 
  ID_LOCAL,
  count(*) as TOTAL,
  SUM(CASE ID_STATUS WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [ID_STATUS=0],
  SUM(CASE ID_STATUS WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [ID_STATUS=1],
  SUM(CASE ID_STATUS WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [ID_STATUS=2],
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID_LOCAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [SQL Server's PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) operator.